# Update RecyclerView with call BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a recycler view in my fragment and I want update my recycler view each time push message ocuured in Broadcast Receiver .My Problem is when receiver call , it replace new item with previous item but i want to create new row and previous items still exist. I searched a lot but have no success . Here is my fragment which has Broadcast receiver in it

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View drawer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notif_list, container, false);
    rv = (RecyclerView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                // new push notification is received
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Push notification is received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
                timestamp = intent.getStringExtra("timestamp");
                Log.d("message -->", message);
                Log.d("title -->", title);
                Log.d("time -->", timestamp);
                MessageObj messageObj = new MessageObj(message,title,timestamp);

                getDataSet(messageObj.getMessage(),messageObj.getTitle(),messageObj.getDate());

            }
        }
    };

    return drawer;
}


private void getDataSet(String message,String title,String date) {
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList<MessageObj>();

        MessageObj obj = new MessageObj(message,title,date);
        Log.d("result size :",results.size()+"");
        results.add(results.size(),obj);
    mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(getActivity(), results);
    rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you are creating a new `results` ArrayList and new Adapter each time you receive a broadcast.  You need to create the array list and adapter once outside the scope of the broadcast receiver.  Then simply add to the array list when you get a broadcast.  Then call [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on your adapter to have it update the UI.

Comment: Excuse me , one more question . if i close app all items remove How can save them ?? Should i use sharedpreference??

Comment: It's a bad practice store data as preference, the data retrieve is slower and not indexed, so is better store the data in a database or if it's just few lines, put then in a file.